# What's this weird black line on the topbar of a site I moderate?

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, moderators

When browsing the site on mobile - haven't yet tested on desktop - I see a little black line on the topbar of my mod site. It looks almost like someone used a freehand marker to draw over something.

[image: screenshot of Literature.SE topbar, showing 1 flag and a black line]

(Screenshot not edited in any way aside from cropping.)

This same line does not appear on other sites, such as here on Meta.SE or on Scifi.SE.

[image: screenshot of Scifi.SE topbar, with no black line]

This seems like a rather odd design bug, so I'm just curious what's going on here. I don't have any extensions or userscripts installed, as this is mobile.

Comment: Looks like a horizontal scrollbar for the section of buttons between the search button and the site switcher, inclusive. It's not present on the non-mod site because there's no potential for horizontal overflow there.

Comment: If only there was a dropdown menu that could be used to display navigation links in mobile

Comment: It is very low contrast. Can you add a red arrow (or similar) pointing to it?